# strtotime equivalent in .NET

Tags: .net, string, parsing, datetime, strtotime

Is there an equivalent of PHP's `strtotime()` function working on .NET Framework. I'm talking about it's capacity to handle strings likes:

- strtotime("**now**")
- strtotime("10 September 2000")
- strtotime("**+1 day**")
- strtotime("**+1 week**")
- strtotime("**+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds**")
- strtotime("**next Thursday**")
- strtotime("**last Monday**")

Obviously `DateTime.Parse()` and `Convert.ToDateTime()` don't do that.

The closest I've found is a small class which only handles a few of those: http://refactormycode.com/codes/488-parse-relative-date

**EDIT:** I'm *not* interested in C# compile-time features. The problem is **converting human relative date/time strings** to *DateTime* at runtime (i.e., "now" --> DateTime.Now and such).

Comment: Note that depending on the target audience or usage scenarios of your application, you might run into serious I16N issues here. While things as "now" might easily translate into many different languages, "+1 day" or "next Thursday", etc. might not. (Been there, tried that, given up (on too complex variations) ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure if strtotime() supports various languages. English only is enough.

Comment: Apparently it does not (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php vs. http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.relative.php). However, if you only need to care about English, than that is of course also not an issue for a C#/.NET version.

Comment: Might want to see [natural-language-date-time-parser-for-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689/natural-language-date-time-parser-for-net)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As so far there is no answer, I made it based on the example given. It supports most cases except those like "last Thurday" (or other days of the week).

```
/// <summary>
/// Parse a date/time string.
/// 
/// Can handle relative English-written date times like:
///  - "-1 day": Yesterday
///  - "+12 weeks": Today twelve weeks later
///  - "1 seconds": One second later from now.
///  - "5 days 1 hour ago"
///  - "1 year 2 months 3 weeks 4 days 5 hours 6 minutes 7 seconds"
///  - "today": This day at midnight.
///  - "now": Right now (date and time).
///  - "next week"
///  - "last month"
///  - "2010-12-31"
///  - "01/01/2010 1:59 PM"
///  - "23:59:58": Today at the given time.
/// 
/// If the relative time includes hours, minutes or seconds, it's relative to now,
/// else it's relative to today.
/// </summary>
internal class RelativeDateParser
{
    private const string ValidUnits = "year|month|week|day|hour|minute|second";

    /// <summary>
    /// Ex: "last year"
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Regex _basicRelativeRegex = new Regex(@"^(last|next) +(" + ValidUnits + ")$");

    /// <summary>
    /// Ex: "+1 week"
    /// Ex: " 1week"
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Regex _simpleRelativeRegex = new Regex(@"^([+-]?\d+) *(" + ValidUnits + ")s?$");

    /// <summary>
    /// Ex: "2 minutes"
    /// Ex: "3 months 5 days 1 hour ago"
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Regex _completeRelativeRegex = new Regex(@"^(?: *(\d) *(" + ValidUnits + ")s?)+( +ago)?$");

    public DateTime Parse(string input)
    {
        // Remove the case and trim spaces.
        input = input.Trim().ToLower();

        // Try common simple words like "yesterday".
        var result = TryParseCommonDateTime(input);
        if (result.HasValue)
            return result.Value;

        // Try common simple words like "last week".
        result = TryParseLastOrNextCommonDateTime(input);
        if (result.HasValue)
            return result.Value;

        // Try simple format like "+1 week".
        result = TryParseSimpleRelativeDateTime(input);
        if (result.HasValue)
            return result.Value;

        // Try first the full format like "1 day 2 hours 10 minutes ago".
        result = TryParseCompleteRelativeDateTime(input);
        if (result.HasValue)
            return result.Value;

        // Try parse fixed dates like "01/01/2000".
        return DateTime.Parse(input);
    }

    private static DateTime? TryParseCommonDateTime(string input)
    {
        switch (input)
        {
            case "now":
                return DateTime.Now;
            case "today":
                return DateTime.Today;
            case "tomorrow":
                return DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
            case "yesterday":
                return DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    private DateTime? TryParseLastOrNextCommonDateTime(string input)
    {
        var match = _basicRelativeRegex.Match(input);
        if (!match.Success)
            return null;

        var unit = match.Groups[2].Value;
        var sign = string.Compare(match.Groups[1].Value, "next", true) == 0 ? 1 : -1;
        return AddOffset(unit, sign);
    }

    private DateTime? TryParseSimpleRelativeDateTime(string input)
    {
        var match = _simpleRelativeRegex.Match(input);
        if (!match.Success)
            return null;

        var delta = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value);
        var unit = match.Groups[2].Value;
        return AddOffset(unit, delta);
    }

    private DateTime? TryParseCompleteRelativeDateTime(string input)
    {
        var match = _completeRelativeRegex.Match(input);
        if (!match.Success)
            return null;

        var values = match.Groups[1].Captures;
        var units = match.Groups[2].Captures;
        var sign = match.Groups[3].Success ? -1 : 1;
        Debug.Assert(values.Count == units.Count);

        var dateTime = UnitIncludeTime(units) ? DateTime.Now : DateTime.Today;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; ++i)
        {
            var value = sign*Convert.ToInt32(values[i].Value);
            var unit = units[i].Value;

            dateTime = AddOffset(unit, value, dateTime);
        }

        return dateTime;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add/Remove years/days/hours... to a datetime.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="unit">Must be one of ValidUnits</param>
    /// <param name="value">Value in given unit to add to the datetime</param>
    /// <param name="dateTime">Relative datetime</param>
    /// <returns>Relative datetime</returns>
    private static DateTime AddOffset(string unit, int value, DateTime dateTime)
    {
        switch (unit)
        {
            case "year":
                return dateTime.AddYears(value);
            case "month":
                return dateTime.AddMonths(value);
            case "week":
                return dateTime.AddDays(value * 7);
            case "day":
                return dateTime.AddDays(value);
            case "hour":
                return dateTime.AddHours(value);
            case "minute":
                return dateTime.AddMinutes(value);
            case "second":
                return dateTime.AddSeconds(value);
            default:
                throw new Exception("Internal error: Unhandled relative date/time case.");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add/Remove years/days/hours... relative to today or now.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="unit">Must be one of ValidUnits</param>
    /// <param name="value">Value in given unit to add to the datetime</param>
    /// <returns>Relative datetime</returns>
    private static DateTime AddOffset(string unit, int value)
    {
        var now = UnitIncludesTime(unit) ? DateTime.Now : DateTime.Today;
        return AddOffset(unit, value, now);
    }

    private static bool UnitIncludeTime(CaptureCollection units)
    {
        foreach (Capture unit in units)
            if (UnitIncludesTime(unit.Value))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    private static bool UnitIncludesTime(string unit)
    {
        switch (unit)
        {
            case "hour":
            case "minute":
            case "second":
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure there are improvements possible but it should handle most cases in English. Please comment if you see improvements (like locale errors or such).

EDIT: Fixed to be relative to now if the relative time includes time.

Comment: As I said in my answer you might want to try a range of date formats - see the example here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8.aspx

Comment: Accepting my own answer sounds unfair but unless someone find any other solution that answers the problem, I'll have to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The DateTime struct has several methods and properties to get what you need:

```
DateTime.Now;
DateTime.Parse("10 September 2000");
DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
DateTime.Now.AddDays(9).AddHours(4).AddSeconds(2);
// And so on
```

If the functionality provided by the DateTime struct isn't enough, I'd suggest checking out [the noda-time project](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/wiki/Welcome) (by Jon Skeet).

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not answering the question: Relative DateTime String --> DataTime object

Comment: @Wernight - You're right. I didn't see the edit about trying to do this at runtime. I'm still seeing what else is out there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the 'correct' answer here is to use something like https://github.com/robertwilczynski/nChronic. It's a port of the Ruby equivalent and can parse a wide range of date time formats, as listed here: http://chronic.rubyforge.org/ in the 'Examples' section (scroll down).

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to write your own method.

"now" is just `DateTime.Now`.

"+1 day" would be `DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)` for example.

So you'll need to parse your string looking for this type of input and then call the appropriate `DateTime` method. The fall-through case would be to pass the string through [`DateTime.Parse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8.aspx) with different DateTimeStyles.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(10,10,2010)
Response.Write(date.ToShortDateTimeString());
Response.Write(date.Year);
date = DateTime.Now;
```

etc etc

Comment: He's asking about Date/Time manipulation in .NET - how is he *not* asking that?

Comment: I'm not asking about Date/Time manipulation but conversion from string that are relative dates.

Comment: Understood. Then just use date.AddDays(1).ToShortDateTimeString(); etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way this to write extension methods to DateTime to handle your needs.

Maybe, it can be OSS, so the community can help you to implement it.