# strtotime for C# (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, date, strtotime

Do you know of a strtotime equivalent in C#(.NET) even for other languages than English (i.e. Slovak version of 25th January is 25 Január).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [strtotime equivalent in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420988/strtotime-equivalent-in-net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent in c#.  There is `Date.Parse()` which converts a string to a `Datetime` object.  This combined with `CultureInfo` class should achieve the desired affect.

See the answer at : [strtotime equivalent in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420988/strtotime-equivalent-in-net)

Answer (score 1):

You have [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx) that parses a string into a DateTime.