# Convert casual language to date

Tags: .net, humanizer

I'm looking for a library for .NET which will take a date string like "two hours ago" or "3", meaning today at 3PM, and convert it to an actual date. [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#humanize-datetime) seems to do the opposite, taking a date and converting it to a more human-readable date, but I can't find anything that does it this way round. Any suggestions?

Comment: For some reason people are voting to close this question, even though there are very similar questions elsewhere on the site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495487/is-there-any-python-library-for-parsing-dates-and-times-from-a-natural-language http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689/natural-language-date-time-parser-for-net

Comment: Rob, Both are very old questions. Quite some time back, but after those questions were posted, what was [considered on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (see #4) changed. Questions asking for off-site resources are no longer on-topic. Closing old questions is something that happens slowly. Someone willing and able has to see the question, and vote/flag them for closure. The Q goes into a review queue which is *always* full of several thousand questions. Five people have to vote to close each one, and votes eventually expire. Each person who can vote, gets only 50 such votes/day.

Comment: I would have loved to have found the answer I now have to this question when I first asked this a few weeks back. It seems strange that something of value to me, along with the two questions I reference above with a large number of upvotes, should be considered not fit for this site. Will they be deleted too?

Comment: This question, and those, will not be [automatically deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). They may be deleted, if (at least) 3 users with enough reputation vote to delete them, but it's unusual for that to happen due to A) the reputation score required to be able to do so is *much* higher, and B) the number of available delete votes is *much* lower. Basically, such votes are usually held in reserve for questions which are much more deserving of being deleted.

Comment: If you are looking for software recommendations (including libraries, etc), such questions are, generally, [on-topic](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nChronic seems to do the job: https://github.com/robertwilczynski/nChronic